# C# issue with a json string if value is null

Tags: c#, string, json

I'm using the following code:

```
if (e.Data.MessageArray[0] == "!streams")
{
  try
  {
    WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
    var data = webclient.DownloadString("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=dotademon");
    JArray ja = JArray.Parse(data);

    WebClient webclient2 = new WebClient();
    var data2 = webclient2.DownloadString("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=trixilulz");
    JArray ja2 = JArray.Parse(data2);

    WebClient webclient3 = new WebClient();
    var data3 = webclient3.DownloadString("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=thepremierleague");
    JArray ja3 = JArray.Parse(data3);

    string streamingString = "Live right now: ";
    streamingString += (char)3 + "03EG.Demon" + (char)15 + " - " + "Viewers: " + ja[0]["channel_count"] + " - " + "http://www.justin.tv/dotademon" + (char)3 + "03 Mouz.Trixi" + (char)15 + " - " + "Viewers: " + ja2[0]["channel_count"] + " - " + "http://www.justin.tv/trixilulz" + (char)3 + "03 The Premier League" + (char)15 + " - " + "Viewers: " + ja3[0]["channel_count"] + " - " + "http://www.justin.tv/thepremierleague";
    irc.SendMessage(SendType.Message, e.Data.Channel, streamingString);

    Console.WriteLine("EG.Demon is " + ja[0]["format"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Mouz.Trixi is " + ja[2]["format"]);
    Console.WriteLine("The Premier League is " + ja[3]["format"]);
  }
  catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
  {
    //catch something
  }
}
```

However, if one of the streams aren't online, then it doesn't output that string at all. Even if 2 are online and 1 is offline and vice versa. However, if they're all online, then it outputs it correctly like:

```
Live right now: EG.Demon - Viewers: 164 - http://www.justin.tv/dotademon Mouz.Trixi - Viewers: 49 - http://www.justin.tv/trixilulz The Premier League - Viewers: 2992 - http://www.justin.tv/thepremierleague
```

To demonstrate it with outputting to console, here is that code, it essentially does the same thing as the above code, but sends it to the console, same issue though obviously:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Test
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      try
      {
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        var data = webclient.DownloadString("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=dotademon");
        JArray ja = JArray.Parse(data);

        WebClient webclient2 = new WebClient();
        var data2 = webclient2.DownloadString("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=trixilulz");
        JArray ja2 = JArray.Parse(data2);

        WebClient webclient3 = new WebClient();
        var data3 = webclient3.DownloadString("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=thepremierleague");
        JArray ja3 = JArray.Parse(data3);

        string streamingString = "Live right now: ";
        streamingString += (char)3 + "03EG.Demon" + (char)15 + " - " + "Viewers: " + ja[0]["channel_count"] + " - " + "http://www.justin.tv/dotademon" + (char)3 + "03 Mouz.Trixi" + (char)15 + " - " + "Viewers: " + ja2[0]["channel_count"] + " - " + "http://www.justin.tv/trixilulz" + (char)3 + "03 The Premier League" + (char)15 + " - " + "Viewers: " + ja3[0]["channel_count"] + " - " + "http://www.justin.tv/thepremierleague";
        Console.WriteLine(streamingString);
      }
      catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
      {
        //do something
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
Live right now: EG.Demon - Viewers: 164 - http://www.justin.tv/dotademon Mouz.Trixi - Viewers: 49 - http://www.justin.tv/trixilulz The Premier League - Viewers: 2992 - http://www.justin.tv/thepremierleague
```

My question is, how can I use this as a string but output it still if it's online and not output the rest if it's offline. When at least one of them are offline, then it doesn't output it at all. It checks if it's online if it finds channel_count in the json, because if it's offline, the json file contains nothing, just []. It's the only approach I know of to check if it's online/offline. I'm using JSON.Net by the way.

Comment: I would suggest using streaminString = string.Format or use a stringbuilder when building complex strings.. I would not be surprised if the error is in the operator overload +=

Comment: I guess you get an exception when calling `webclientX.DownloadString`?  Have you ever stepped through the code with the debugger?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thanks for the tip! Seems like you were right. :)

Comment: @Jan Hmm, didn't think of that, but thanks for the tip. I've learnt a lot from this topic. I'm new to learning C# however, so it's helping me tons and orip's answer works perfectly. Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `ja.Count` to see if you got a response.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder("Live right now: ");
if (ja.Count > 0)
  sb.Append(string.Format("EG.Demon - Viewers: {0} - http://www.justin.tv/dotademon", ja[0]["channel_count"]));
if (ja2.Count > 0)
  //...
if (ja3.Count > 0)
  //...

irc.SendMessage(SendType.Message, e.Data.Channel, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: It works great but just one slight issue. If all streams are offline, it still outputs Live right now: 
And that's it. But the code is working fine, it's just when all streams are offline it still outputs Live right now: when it shouldn't at all if they are all offline.